# Angular detects field as undefined when it's initialized in the object

Tags: angular, typescript, spring, h2

When I'm trying to get a property of the object "User" it's detected as undefined but when I make a console log of the entire object the field appears with the data.

Console log:

```
perfil.component.ts:42 undefined
perfil.component.ts:48 
{recordNumber: '00001A', name: 'Victor Manuel Arenas', dni: '75499109E', birthDate: '2000-12-04', phoneNumber: '678678678', …}
address
: 
"C\\Lorca 31"
birthDate
: 
"2000-12-04"
dni
: 
"75499109E"
email
: 
"victormanuel.arenas@univ.com"
name
: 
"Victor Manuel Arenas"
parking
: 
null
password
: 
"$2a$10$auBcwSsgKBWMTUUFToVb1OklqDP4O0LvW9F7vqWjnVZAGFzOVtfg6"
phoneNumber
: 
"678678678"
profilepic
: 
"profilepic_00001A.jpg"
recordNumber
: 
"00001A"
role
: 
"ALUMNO"
```

Method:

```
checking(){
    if(this.sesion.user != null){
      console.log(this.sesion.user.phonenumber);
      if(this.sesion.user.phonenumber === undefined) {
        alert("myProperty value is the special value `undefined`");
      }
    }
    
    console.log(this.sesion.user);
  }
```

Interface of the obj:

```
import { Parking } from "./Parking";

export interface User {
    recordNumber: string;
    name: string;
    dni: string;
    birthdate: Date;
    phonenumber: string|null;
    email: string;
    address: string;
    profilepic: string|null;
    role: string;
    password: string;
    parking: Parking;
}
```

I have been trying to get the field of other ways and other pages. It's not a problem of backend because the data arrives to front.
It's not problem of the object because the field have the data.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo (`phonenumber` vs `phoneNumber`).
In your interface and `checking` method you refer to `phonenumber`. The log states the property is typed `phoneNumber` though (note the capital `N`).

```
const a = {foo: 'bar'};
console.log(a.foo) // => 'bar'
console.log(a.FOO) // => undefined
```

The property access is case sensitive.